# Importing BigQuery data to Power BI, aggregate column is showing as if it's a nested table

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, google-analytics-4

I'm processing Google Analytics 4 (GA4) data in BigQuery, and then importing it into Power BI to build dashboards with.

I've got a handful of pretty simple queries that all have the same issue though. One of the columns, which is an aggregate/count, is being read by PBI as if it was a JSON of the whole row (I think).

I've created several dashboards and reports using GA4 > BigQuery > Power BI over the last year or so. This issue has only started happening since I went back to re-create the queries and tables I originally made now that I am much more comfortable with all of it (or thought I was!). I didn't delete or overwrite any of my existing data, it's all new queries and new tables.

The BigQuery query:

```
SELECT
  Date,
  Time,
  IF (ENDS_WITH(uri,'/'), 
    LEFT(uri,LENGTH(uri)-1), 
    uri) as Page,
  COUNT(distinct unique) as Pageviews,
  COUNT(distinct SessionID) as UniquePageviews,
  SessionID

FROM (
  SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(replace(replace((select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'page_location'),'https://',''),'http://',''),r'[^?]*') as uri,
    date(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp),'America/Edmonton') as Date,
    FORMAT_TIME('%R', time(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), MINUTE),'America/Edmonton')) as Time,
    CAST((select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id') as string) as SessionID,
    concat(event_bundle_sequence_id,event_timestamp) as unique

  FROM
    `lateral-store-###`.`analytics_###`.`events_*`
  WHERE 
    event_name = 'page_view'
)

GROUP BY
  Date,
  Time,
  Page,
  SessionID

  ORDER BY Date DESC, Page ASC
```

The resulting table in BigQuery:

| Date (date) | Time (string) | Page (string) | Pageviews (integer) | UniquePageviews (integer) | SessionID (string) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/14/2023 | 12:50 | domain.com/portal/dashboard | 1 | 1 | 1678819768 |
| 3/14/2023 | 10:28 | domain.com/portal/dashboard | 2 | 1 | 1678810211 |

And yet when I import the table into Power BI, what I actually get is

| Date (date) | Time (string) | Page (string) | Pageviews (whole number) | UniquePageviews (whole number) | SessionID (string) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/14/2023 | 12:50 | domain.com/portal/dashboard | {"v":{"f":[{"v":"2023-03-14"},{"v":"15:37"},{"v":"domain.com/portal/dashboard"},{"v":"1"},{"v":"1"},{"v":"1678825862"}]}} | 1 | 1678819768 |
| 3/14/2023 | 10:28 | domain.com/portal/dashboard | {"v":{"f":[{"v":"2023-03-14"},{"v":"18:44"},{"v":"domain.com/portal/dashboard"},{"v":"2"},{"v":"1"},{"v":"1678840716"}]}} | 1 | 1678810211 |

Not surprisingly, when I try to apply my changes, I get an error that there is a type mismatch because the data in Pageviews is not a number of any kind. I think that's JSON formatting, and was an issue I had to deal with when I was first trying to get GA4 up and running.

Comment: Does renaming `unique` to something else help?  Maybe a reserved keyword in PowerBI?  Does not seem to be a BigQuery issue.

Comment: Renaming unique to UniqueID didn't change anything, but then I also renamed Pageviews to AllPageviews and that seemed to do it. When I rolled back the query to try changing only one of those two, it didn't work. So, I guess I'll call this solved even though I don't understand why it worked, lmao